# Laravel Get Value from Unquoted JSON

Tags: laravel

I have this JSON response from a controller:

```
{"success":1,"message":"Transaction assigned to customer."}
```

How do I get the success key to print 1? I have tried

```
$json = json_decode($assign);
$success = $json->success;
```

But getting error: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working:

```
$response = $data = {"success":1,"message":"Transaction assigned to customer."}; 
$data = collect($response);

$success = $data["original"]["success"];
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case as you explained in the comments:
use this one

first decode the json as object,

```
$data = '{"success":1,"message":"Transaction assigned to customer."}';
$json = json_decode($data, false);
```

this lets you to access your value using `$json->success`

note: the second parameter of `json_decode` is boolean and named associative which is true by default.

and do your logic...

in the Log part, `Log::info` has two parameter first one is `message` and expected to be a string.

and second one is `context` and expected to be an array. just change your `$json` into an associative array and send it to `Log::info` like this:

```
Log::info("some message", (array)$json);
```

Comment: $data = {"success":1,"message":"Transaction assigned to customer."};

$json = json_decode($data, false);
\Log::info($json);

That Log yields null

Comment: \Log::info has two parameters, first parameter is a message and should be string, the second one is context an should be array. i think best way is to send an string like transaction assigned ... and for context part, dont send an object. send an array it will show the array like a json in laravel.log. i tested this:   $data = '{"success":1,"message":"Transaction assigned to customer."}';
    $json = json_decode($data, true);
    \Log::info("some message", $json);  and works fine.

Comment: I have managed to get it working: 

$response = $data = {"success":1,"message":"Transaction assigned to customer."}; 
$data = collect($response);

$success = $data["original"]["success"];